# Per instance Liferay portlet parameters

Tags: apache-flex, query-string, portlet, liferay

I have a portlet. Inside of this portlet I have Flex application that displays some stats using charts.

Flex recognize what stats it needs to display by a parameter provided in `flashVars`.  I need to create one page for each kind of stats, so every page must contain this portlet.

My problem is that I can't find a way to provide a different parameter to each of the portlet instances so that they display different data.

My only solution up until now was to create a different portlet for each kind of stats, but that's really lame.  I also tried to provide a Query String value on the 'Manage Pages' form, but I couldn't retrieve parameters I defined there in any way (tried `request.getParameter()`, `renderRequest.getParameter()`, etc.).

Is there any way to achieve such functionality using multiple instances of a single portlet?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the PortletPreferences API is intended to solve, in Liferay, you can set your `liferay-portlet.xml` to determine whether `PortletPreferences` are owned by the user, or the layout group (the default).

Then you can implement an edit screen (or config, but edit is the cross-platform standard) to provide a mechanism for users to modify the parameters.